# How to set vibration and sound in a notification

Tags: android, notifications

```
public void cancelNotification()
    {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(AcceptUserRequest.this);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.lo);
        builder.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getApplicationContext().getResources(),
                R.mipmap.peoplehelperlogo));

    builder.setContentTitle("PEOPLE HELPER");
    builder.setContentText("Accepted request has been cancelled");
    builder.setAutoCancel(true);

    Intent intent = new Intent(AcceptUserRequest.this, BroadcastFragment.class); //creates an explicit intent
    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(AcceptUserRequest.this);
    stackBuilder.addParentStack(AcceptUserRequest.this); //adds the intent
    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);  //put the intent to the top of the stack
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //(id, flag) //creates a pending intent
    builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent); //adds the PendingIntent to the builder
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) AcceptUserRequest.this.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, builder.build());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These are some of the dummy codes, hope this helps you.

private static NotificationCompat.Builder buildNotificationCommon(Context _context, .....) {

```
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(_context).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).......;
 //Vibration
    builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });

 //LED
    builder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);

 //Ton
    builder.setSound(Uri.parse("uri://sadfasdfasdf.mp3"));

return builder;
```

}

Comment: I tried inserting it in my code but it's not working.

Comment: @LMae Did you add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />` to manifest?

Answer (score 0):

It might be help you

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new      NotificationCompat.Builder(_context).setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis()).......;
 //Vibration      
builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });

//LED        
builder.setLights(Color.RED, 3000, 3000);

//Ton
builder.setSound(Uri.parse("uri://sadfasdfasdf.mp3"));

return builder;
```

Comment: I tried inserting it in my code but it's not working.

Comment: I inserted it under builder.setAutoCancel(true);

Comment: first try ony sinle case like
builder.setVibrate(new long[] { 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000, 1000 });